# Scikit-learn pipeline returns list of zeroes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

I am not able to understand why I am getting this wrong pipeline output.

Pipeline code:

```py
my_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[ 
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler())
])
```

Real data:

```py
real = [[0.02498, 0.0, 1.89, 0.0, 0.518, 6.54, 59.7, 6.2669, 1.0, 422.0, 15.9, 389.96, 8.65]]
```

The pipeline output that I want:

```py
want = [[-0.44228927, -0.4898311 , -1.37640684, -0.27288841, -0.34321545, 0.36524574, -0.33092752,  1.20235683, -1.0016859 ,  0.05733231, -1.21003475,  0.38110555, -0.57309194]]
```

But after running the below code:

```py
getting = my_pipeline.fit_transform(real)
```

I am getting:

```py
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: The issue is that `real` has shape `(1, 13)` and is therefore considered 1 sample on 13 features, instead of 13 samples on 1 feature. To resolve this issue you can cast `real` to `numpy` array and transpose it: `my_pipeline.fit_transform(np.transpose(np.array(real)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

This is an expected behavior because you define the data as a list.

After the first step of the pipeline i.e. the SimpleImputer, the returned output is a numpy array with shape `(1,13)`.

```
si = SimpleImputer()
si_out = si.fit_transform(real)

si_out.shape
# (1, 13)
```

**The returned `(1,13)` array is the problem here.** This is because the `StandardScaler`, removes the mean and divides by the std each column. **Thus, it "sees" 13 columns and the final output is all 0s since the means have been removed.**

```
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit_transform(si_out)
```

returns

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

### The solution

It seems that you have only one variable/feature named `real`.
**Just reshape it before fitting.**

```
import numpy as np

real = np.array([[0.02498, 0.0, 1.89, 0.0, 0.518, 6.54, 59.7, 6.2669, 1.0, 422.0, 15.9, 389.96, 8.65]]).reshape(-1,1)

my_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[ 
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler())
])
my_pipeline.fit_transform(real)

array([[-0.48677709],
       [-0.4869504 ],
       [-0.47383804],
       [-0.4869504 ],
       [-0.48335664],
       [-0.44157747],
       [-0.07276633],
       [-0.44347217],
       [-0.48001264],
       [ 2.44078289],
       [-0.37664007],
       [ 2.21849716],
       [-0.4269388 ]])
```

Comment: hey @seralouk let me confirm one thing, the mean that you stated (which is being subtracted) is calculated from , "All the rows of a given column". Right? in the 2D-Array

Comment: yes. the mean and std is based on each column because sklearn treats each column as a feature/variable